# how do i write user input to another file? HTML, php, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my html appointment form i created, it's a simple form that obtains a day, a time, and a name. I'd just like to know how to write this information to another file for later use, or also possibly send the information to an email address. I can't seem to figure it out. I'm still relatively new with web development and have tried many different methods to no avail. any help at all would be appreciated.

[image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IXLS.jpg)

```html
<div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
  <div id="tab1">
    <div class="submit-form">
      <h4>
        Setup an appointment
      </h4>
      <form id="form-submit" action="" method="get">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <fieldset>
              <label for="Date">Date:</label> <select required=""
              name='from' onchange='this.form.()'>
                <option value="">
                  Select a day...
                </option>
                <option value="Monday">
                  Monday
                </option>
                <option value="Tuesday">
                  Tuesday
                </option>
                <option value="Wednesday">
                  Wednesday
                </option>
                <option value="Thursday">
                  Thursday
                </option>
                <option value="Friday">
                  Friday
                </option>
              </select>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <fieldset>
              <label for="Time">Time:</label> <select required=""
              name='to' onchange='this.form.()'>
                <option value="">
                  Select a Time...
                </option>
                <option value="9:15 A.M">
                  9:15 AM
                </option>
                <option value="10:15 A.M">
                  10:15 AM
                </option>
                <option value="11:15 A.M">
                  11:15 AM
                </option>
                <option value="12:45 P.M">
                  12:45 PM
                </option>
                <option value="1:45 P.M">
                  1:15 PM
                </option>
                <option value="2:45 P.M">
                  2:15 PM
                </option>
                <option value="3:15 P.M">
                  3:15 PM
                </option>
                <option value="4:15 P.M">
                  4:15 PM
                </option>
              </select>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="nLabel">
              <fieldset>
                <label style="margin-left:-50px" for=
                "Name">Name:</label>
                <div class="nBox">
                  <fieldset>
                    <input style="margin-left:-110px" type=
                    "text" />
                    <div class="Btn">
                      <fieldset>
                        <button type="submit" style=
                        "margin-left:-69px" id="sBtn" class=
                        "button" value="click">OK</button>
                      </fieldset>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use php on the backend? The first step would be creating a php file in the same directory (like index.php), then sticking "index.php" in the 'action' part of the form tag. The action is where info gets posted.

Comment: there are many php form handling tutorials out there that should get you there rest of the way. i.e https://alvinalexander.com/php/php-simple-form-example-get-post-isset looks pretty clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you out. I have not done any validations on front-end or on the back-end. I would suggest you have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp; https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

home.php:

```
<form action="appointment.php" method="POST">
    Name: <input name="name" type="text"><br/><br/>
    Select Day: <select name="day">
        <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
        <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
        <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
        <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    </select><br/><br/>
    Select Time: <select name="appointment_time">
        <option value="9:15 A.M.">9:15 A.M.</option>
        <option value="10:15 A.M.">10:15 A.M.</option>
        <option value="11:15 A.M.">11:15 A.M.</option>
        <option value="12:45 P.M.">12:45 P.M.</option>
        <option value="1:45 P.M.">1:45 P.M.</option>
        <option value="2:45 P.M.">2:45 P.M.</option>
        <option value="3:15 P.M.">3:15 P.M.</option>
        <option value="4:15 P.M.">4:15 P.M.</option>
    </select><br/><br/>
    <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

appointment.php :

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$day = $_POST["day"];
$appointment_time = $_POST["appointment_time"];
$txt = "\n".$name."\t".$day."\t".$appointment_time;
file_put_contents('appointments.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
header("Location: home.php");
?>
```

Comment: you guys are awesome, i greatly appreciate the help! I honestly couldn't appreciate it enough.